# Android Locale Issues

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

I need a text to be shown in English and Hindi but, by default it is shown in English.

I have two buttons with labels "English" and "Hindi"

When clicked on Hindi, it is showing in hindi, but when i click english, text is not getting back to english again.

The following is the code i am using

```
Button en_Button,hi_Button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setLanguage("en");

    en_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.en_Button);
    hi_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hi_Button);

    en_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLanguage("en");
        }
    });

    hi_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLanguage("hi");
        }
    });
}

public void setLanguage(String language)
{
    String languageToLoad  = language; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

What is that I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did check Answer I Posted ?

Comment: i am confused because, when i click on HIndi, without restarting the activity, text is getting converted to Hindi. It's not getting converted to English when i click the english button.

Comment: restarting activity is only solution.

Comment: Is there any error or log @Lakshman Pilaka

Comment: i am restarting the activity using your code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not give you effect runtime. You need to start your activity again with the language `hi`.

Simple Workaround for that

1. Store language you want to change in sharedPreference.
2. After set preference. startActivity(getIntent());
3. now every time you loading "en". instead of that load value form the SharedPreferences

   ```
   public String getAppLanguage() {
       SharedPreferences pref; = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       return pref.getString(APP_LANG, "en");
   }

   public void setAppLanguage(String language) {
       SharedPreferences pref; = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       Editor editor = pref.edit();
       editor.putString(APP_LANG, language);
       editor.commit();
   }
   ```